# How to search a list of objects given just one word

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object

```
Const obj=[{
"name":"Teak",
"Width":"20",
"general":["it is dark","it is 
brown","it is blue"],
"Characteristics":["blue","black"]
} ]
```

So please  if the objects were much, i wanna make it possible that no matter what the person inputs, it will go through each object and return the object or objects that has that property. e.g if the person was to input blue, without anything else, how will i do it that js will go inside each obj then each characteristics and check if blue is there and then return it.

Or e.g it the person was to press dark, it has to go into general then check each sentence and if dark is there, it will return that object and other object with dark feature not minding if the other objects have general like "it is dark" 
Now i am assuming this array of object will be on my js... Please help anyone.
This was what I tried doing

```
var allbooks = 
obj.reduce(function(accumulator, 
currentValue) {
return 
n=currentValue.includes("black");
}, []);
console.log(allbooks)
```

But this is not looking in anyway correct

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducaple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach would be to convert the obj to string and invoke `string.include`.

```js
let obj = {
  "name": "Teak",
  "Width": "20",
  "general": [
    "it is dark",
    "it is brown",
    "it is blue"
  ],
  "Characteristics": ["blue", "black"]
};

let check = (obj, word) =>
  JSON.stringify(obj).includes(word);

console.log(check(obj, 'blue'));
console.log(check(obj, 'red'));
```

This has a few problems, e.g. cyclic objects can't be converted to strings (e.g. `a = {}; a.x = a;`) and this will search property keys as well (which may or may not be desired?).

A more robust solution would be to iterate all properties, check numbers and strings for matching `word`, and recursively iterate arrays and objects, while checking to avoid cyclic iterations (not implemented in below example).

```js
let obj = {
  "name": "Teak",
  "Width": 20,
  "general": [
    "it is dark",
    "it is brown",
    "it is blue"
  ],
  "Characteristics": ["blue", "black"]
};

let check = (obj, word) =>
  Object.values(obj).some(value =>
    typeof value === 'object' ?
      check(value, word) :
      String(value).includes(word));

console.log(check(obj, 'blue'));
console.log(check(obj, 'red'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var obj=[
  {
  "name":"Teak",
  "Width":"20",
  "general":["it is dark","it is brown","it is blue"],
  "Characteristics":["blue","black"]
  },
   {
  "name":"Teak",
  "Width":"20",
  "general":["it is dark","it is brown","it is blue"],
  "Characteristics":["black"]
  }
]

const input = 'blue';

const a = obj.filter(o => {
  return o.Characteristics.includes(input)
})

console.log(a)
```